# How to parameterize username and password in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmx

How to remove hardcoding in the below code?

```
<stringProp name="Authorization.username">user123</stringProp><stringProp name="Authorization.password">pwd123</stringProp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the credentials from JMeter properties.

[image]

When you [run JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) you will be able to pass the credentials via `-J` command-line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Jusername=user123 -Jpassword=pwd123 -t test.jmx .....
```

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Have given like this in HTTP Authorization Manager and used the above command-line arguments to start jmeter. But getting '401' while running the script.

Comment: Worked as expected finally when I added all the urls required in the Authorization Manager and set username and password as mentioned above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a job for User Defined Variables.
As you can see here:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

at par 20.3

> Referencing a variable in a test element is done by bracketing the
> variable name with '${' and '}'.

So basically something like ${jmxUsr} and ${jmxPwd} in your test script.
Values can be assigned in "Test Plan" or "Thread Group" (right click till "User Defined Variables" )

Comment: Tried this way as well giving ${__P(userID)} in user defined variables under Test plan and opening the jmeter through command prompt with jmeter -JuserID=user123 -Jpassword=pwd123 -t test.jmx but still getting 401 when I run the script